# Telling Whether A Tweet Is A Retweet Or Not?

Tags: api, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API in order to pull tweets from specific users. I have it working exactly as I want, except for being able to tell whether or not a specific tweet is original from the user or if it is a retweet.

I'm using the following call:
`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=philiprucker&count=1`

When looking at the results, it appears that I should be able to pull `retweeted` from the results and it should return true or false. However, this is only returning the string `retweet`.

```
$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=$screen_name&count=200" ;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$xml = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($twelement->status as $status) {
    $text = dbEscape(trim($status->text));
    $time = strtotime($status->created_at);
    $id = $status->id;
    $num_retweets = $status->retweet_count;
    $retweet = $status->retweeted;
    dbQuery("INSERT INTO `twitter` (`id`,`screen_name`,`time`,`text`,`hidden`, `numRetweets`, `retweet`) VALUES ('$id','$screen_name','$time','$text','n','$num_retweets','retweet')");
    // dbQuery("INSERT INTO `twitter` (`id`,`screen_name`,`time`,`text`,`hidden`) VALUES ('$id','$screen_name','$time','$text','n')");
}
```

This is the code doing what I describe. I believe all the relevant code is there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are specifically putting the string `retweet` into the table, not the value of `$retweet`.

Comment: Also note @Taylor's good clarifying question below about what you're really trying to store...I'm just pointing out your typo. :)

Comment: Wow I feel stupid. Just wow. Thanks. The little things you miss after looking at the same code for a couple hours.

Answer (score 7):

Quick clarifying question: are you looking to store whether a tweet has ever been retweeted, or are you looking to store whether the user making the request retweeted the tweet?

The "retweeted" boolean field attached to a status is perspectival to the user making the request -- it indicates whether the current user retweeted the tweet or not, not whether the tweet has been retweeted. A non-zero retweet_count would be a better indicator as to whether the tweet has been retweeted or not.

Comment: I'm trying to store whether or not the tweet from the user I am searching is actually his own original content or whether he retweeted someone.

Comment: This question is very valid and you are correct to ask it because this is not actually what I'm attempting to capture. Thanks! Would upvote except I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple `GET` request along with [***Yahoo Query Language (aka YQL)***](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20retweeted%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline.json%3Finclude_entities%3Dtrue%26include_rts%3Dtrue%26screen_name%3Dphiliprucker%26count%3D1%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) to access the `retweeted` node can be achieved like this:

[**jsFiddle DEMO: YQL Rest Query for Twitter Retweeted Status via JSON**](http://jsfiddle.net/KpPaE/)

The callback `json` results are shown below:

```js
cbfunc({
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2012-12-31T09:51:58Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "json": {
    "retweeted": "false"
   }
  }
 }
});
```

And you can also have that returned as `xml` too:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2012-12-31T09:54:49Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <json>
            <retweeted>false</retweeted>
        </json>
    </results>
</query>
```

Here's how the [**YQL Statement**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20retweeted%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline.json%3Finclude_entities%3Dtrue%26include_rts%3Dtrue%26screen_name%3Dphiliprucker%26count%3D1%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) would look like to return the ***retweeted*** node with ether ***true*** or ***false*** as the result:

```
SELECT retweeted FROM json WHERE url="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=philiprucker&count=1"
```

And that simple `GET` request is just a `ajax();` request with success function like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KpPaE/):

```js
// The YQL Statement used below is shown next, starting with the word SELECT:
//
// SELECT retweeted FROM json WHERE url="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=philiprucker&count=1"
//
// View the above YQL Statement using Yahoo Console at: 
// http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20retweeted%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline.json%3Finclude_entities%3Dtrue%26include_rts%3Dtrue%26screen_name%3Dphiliprucker%26count%3D1%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
//
// The variable 'q' below is the Yahoo Rest Query. That is provided after creating the above Yahoo Statement.
// It's provided at the bottom of that web page.

var q = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20retweeted%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline.json%3Finclude_entities%3Dtrue%26include_rts%3Dtrue%26screen_name%3Dphiliprucker%26count%3D1%22&format=json';

// Use simple jQuery .ajax along with the above YQL Rest Statement.
// The benefit of YQL rest statement is we can select the desired node, in this case "retweeted"
$.ajax({
    url: q,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        // Enable to show the jQuery data Object received in the browsers console.
        //console.log(data);

        // If we have data, continue.
        if (data) {

            // Display retweeted value of 'true' or 'false' via browser alert.
            alert('The retweeted status is: ' +  data.query.results.json.retweeted );

        }

    }
});
```

---

**EDIT 2: Retrieve Global Retweeted Value.**

[**Reference: OP's Tweet with Viewable Retweet Count**](https://twitter.com/PostBaron/status/286544211556319233)

[**jsFiddle DEMO: YQL Rest Query for Twitter Global Retweeted Status via HTML**](http://jsfiddle.net/WX3qu/)

This time, the ***total retweeted global count*** of that tweet will be data-scrapped directly from the Twitter page with the tweet. This method does not require to visit the original tweet, as any retweet will show this global count.

To verify that the jsFiddle is showing the actual retweeted count, reference the OP's tweet page using the provided link above.

The process is similar to what's described above, except this time our `.ajax()` `dataType` is `html` and the YQL Statement is as follows:

```html
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="https://twitter.com/PostBaron/status/286544211556319233" AND xpath="//a[@class='request-retweeted-popup']"
```

Notice in the above [**YQL Statement**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FPostBaron%2Fstatus%2F286544211556319233%22%20AND%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%3D%27request-retweeted-popup%27%5D%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) that `XPATH` is also used to access the specific data required. This prevents from downloading the whole HTML webpage, and just that specific data for *Global Tweet Count* is accessed. This is possible since that value is in the webpage anchor with unique *classname* `request-retweeted-popup`. To discover that classname quickly, I used **Inspect Element** tool that the browser has when I hovered over that value on the webpage. Once the classname was known, I fined-tuned the response to return the value in the `<strong>` tags which is the number we want to know.

Naturally, a value of `0` means the tweet has never been retweeted but more importantly signifies that this is the original tweet itself.

The end result is no Twitter API is required since your data-scraping the actual public webpage in order to get the *Global Tweet Count*.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: q,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

        // If we have data, continue.
        if ( $(data).find('.request-retweeted-popup') ) {

            // Store the value of total retweets in this variable.
            var totalRetweets = $(data).find('strong').text();

            // Show browser alert of the totalRetweets value. Change alert() to console.log() for console log browser responses.
            alert('The following Tweet has been retweeted: ' + totalRetweets +  ' times');

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Hank Gay: Please provide feedback to my answer during your bounty period. Thank you!

Comment: I believe this runs into the problem mentioned in [@TaylorSingletary's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8902722/4203): the `retweeted` field tells you whether the current user has retweeted the tweet in question. I want to know whether the tweet in question is itself a retweet of someone else's tweet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please see EDIT 2: Retrieve Global Retweeted Value for your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to do this using only the API? It might be feasible for me to fall back on page scraping, but I **strongly** prefer an API-based solution, and that was the original intent of the bounty (I'll still award it to you if it turns out there isn't a way to do it within the API, which is what I'm beginning to suspect).

Comment: I've looked at the Tweets section in the new [**API v1.1**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1#111) and it's not an API option as you've indicated. In the mean-time, there is another way to data-scrape if a Tweet is a *"all out flat retweet"* using the last method shown in my answer, but to detect the unique words "Retweeted by" on the posted tweet. See the OP's Tweet Retweeted here; approx 13 Tweet [**HERE**](https://twitter.com/LaurieBabinski). Looking at the HTML for that, there's 3 unique `data` attributes to datascrape and compare: `data-retweet-id`, `data-item-id`, and `data-tweet-id`.

Comment: Aha! If you run a GET on a "modern" retweet's URL, it gives you a 302 to the original!

Comment: For each tweet, retweet or not, the day and month at the top right corner is the `permalink` to the original tweet too.

Comment: This [**YQL example**](http://y.ahoo.it/7qIZY) is for member @LaurieBabinski who has retweeted some tweets, including the OP's original tweet (See #12 as of this writing). Each `href="/LaurieBabinski/....` indicates an **original tweet**, while all others indicate a **retweeted tweet**. In all cases, the `/status/` includes the actual webpage of the original tweet, so constructing an absolute URL can be done quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still reading this, I think that perhaps this thread gets to the point more succinctly, and is more correct for the current api (1.1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24041978/1449799

tl;dr
check for existence of retweeted_status on the status object.