# How do you check to see if a specific tweet is retweeted using JavaScript or JQuery when displaying a twitter feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, social-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Telling Whether A Tweet Is A Retweet Or Not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902635/telling-whether-a-tweet-is-a-retweet-or-not)

So I've been working on a twitter feed script that pulls in my feed. I'm wondering how would I go about checking to see if a specific tweet is retweeted, and then if it is retweeted I want to use the information from the retweeted tweet instead. Here's an example associative array of what the twitter API produces for a retweet.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [created_at] => Sun Jan 06 08:28:39 +0000 2013
            [id] => 287838076443705345
            [id_str] => 287838076443705345
            [text] => RT @Fullscreen: Heads-up: many YT partners are reporting issues claiming their videos. It appears to be a YT bug. We will keep you posted.
            [source] => web
            ... 
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 212642904
                    [id_str] => 212642904
                    [name] => Elias Ranz-Schleifer
                    [screen_name] => Xxplosions
                    ... 
                )
                ...
            [retweeted_status] => Array
                (
                    [created_at] => Sun Jan 06 02:08:43 +0000 2013
                    [id] => 287742460824805378
                    [id_str] => 287742460824805378
                    [text] => Heads-up: many YT partners are reporting issues claiming their videos. It appears to be a YT bug. We will keep you posted.
                    ... 
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 238110322
                            [id_str] => 238110322
                            [name] => Fullscreen, Inc.
                            [screen_name] => Fullscreen
                            ... 
                        )
                        ...
                )

            [retweet_count] => 44
            ...
        )

)
```

So essentially I want to replace `[text] => RT @Fullscreen: Heads-up: many...` with `[text] => Heads-up: many...` only if it exists. If it doesn't exist then use the normal method of pulling the information from the tweets. I guess basically what I'm trying to get at is how do I check to see if `[retweeted_status]` exists then pull that information if not then pull the other information. I would like to avoid having the RT in there since it does appear to be possible and to use the information like `id_str, text, screen_name, etc.`

The code I use to get the information for the regular tweet pulling is:

```
id = tweets[i]["id_str"];
twitPic = tweets[0]["user"]["profile_image_url_https"];
content = tweets[i]["text"];
tweetTime = tweets[i]["created_at"];
```

where `i` is replaced by the index in a for loop. If you have any questions about what I'm trying to get at then let me know and I'll be happy to clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the key exists like this:

```
// by using the 'in' operator
content = ('retweeted_status' in tweets[i]) ?  tweets[i]["retweeted_status"] : tweets[i]["text"];
// or by using the method 'hasOwnProperty()'
if(tweets[i].hasOwnProperty('retweeted_status')) {
    content = tweets[i]["retweeted_status"];
} else {
    content = tweets[i]["text"];
}
```

You could also checking for undefined, but this is not an accurate way of testing whether a key exists (What if the key exists but the value is actually undefined?).

Answer (score 0):

```
// save current tweet
var tweet = tweets[i];
var id = tweet.id_str;
var twitPic = tweet.user.profile_image_url_https;
var tweetTime = tweet.created_at;
var isRetweet = Object.prototype.toString.call(tweet.retweeted_status).slice(8, -1) === 'Object';
// try to use text from original tweet
var content = isRetweet ? tweet.retweeted_status.text : tweet.text;
```