# Twitter API: Check if a tweet is a retweet

Tags: twitter

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902635/telling-whether-a-tweet-is-a-retweet-or-not). However I think this has changed on API version 1.1.

If I use the `search/tweets` method, how can I see if the tweet is a RT?
I see that the `retweeted` field always returns `false`. Is there another field I can use for this answer?

Answer (score 47):

If it's a retweet, the tweet will contain a property named `retweeted_status`. To be complete, `retweeted_status` will not appear if the tweet is not a retweet. More info at: [Tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object).

Comment: simply as `hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status')` where `tweet` is instance of the `tweepy.Status`

Comment: How about for Twitter API v2?

Answer (score 4):

By simply checking the property name

**"retweeted_status"**

if you does not find then it's  not RT.

Answer (score 3):

As @Joe Mayo said, check for the `retweeted_status` key on the status object.

I have an example that is not caught by @Apoorv Ashutosh's suggestion.

See: https://twitter.com/gppvt/status/474162466776449024 this will redirect (because it is a retweet) to the original tweet. However if you get this tweet through the twitter API, it has `retweeted_status`. Notice the text does not contain "RT".

Answer (score 2):

The retweeted field is false if the retweet is not done using the retweet button but rahter via RT, so in such a case, just search the "text" field of all tweets for this pattern

RT @

This pattern can be of help, but I don't think there is any other function for this.

Comment: This is not sufficient; users may enter "RT @" in their Tweets and it will not be a real retweet from the perspective of the Twitter API.

Comment: This was the "old" conventional way of RT'ing before twitter implemented official RT's.  As indicated above, the presence of a `retweeted_status` attribute indicates that the tweet is a RT. Also see the Twitter documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

Answer (score 2):

The `retweeted_status` property will exist if the received tweet was retweeted, else you will get the `AttributeError` error. In the case, you want to get rid of retweeted tweets:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    try:
        print "Retweeted ************* \n" + str(status.retweeted_status)
        return 
    except AttributeError:
        print "there is no attribut with name retweeted_status"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit more. (using twitter gem (ruby language))

You can check if its a retweet by checking the tweet and then getting what you need from the retweeted_status hash

```
t = client.status(#########) #function that obtains tweet based on ID where # = tweet ID
puts t.retweeted_status? # returns true or false
t.retweeted_status # returns the actual hash for that
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has mentioned, you can check to see if the `retweeted_status` property exists in the response subfield for that Tweet.

[However, per the current version of the API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html), every Tweet object has the field `retweeted` that stores a boolean value (True or False) that will tell you if a Tweet has been retweeted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "re-tweet" is not actually a quote of an another tweet. In this case, I had to use the `quoted_status` field to get the original tweet, rather than the `retweeted_status` one.

Answer (score 1):

To the ones who are using `Hydrator`[1](https://github.com/DocNow/hydrator) and relying on its `CSV` export of the hydrated `JSONL` file: you can check `reweet_id` (no it's not a typo in version `0.0.12`), and if it's `NA` then it's an original tweet as I found.

```
original_twitter_tweets = twitter_csv_data %>% filter(is.na(reweet_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that retweets are distinguished from regular tweets by the line "RT @..."

The Python code following can be used to identify them:

```
tweettext = str( tweet.text.lower())
if tweettext.startswith("rt @") == True:
    print(tweet.id)
```

Tweet object is the tweet variable.
Tweepy is another tool you may use to manage the Twitter API more easily.