# How to find all the tweet ids that a user has liked on twitter using PYTHON TWEEPY?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, favorites

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet_list=api.favorites.list(screen_name="your_username", count=10)
```

Error : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/fav.py", line 19, in 
tweet_list=api.favorites.list(screen_name="your_username", count=10)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: use `tweet_list=api.favorites(screen_name="put_username_here", count=10)`. remove the `list` attribute, `api.favorites` returns the result in a `list`

Comment: thanks  a lot . And also can you please help me. i'm facing some issue with twitter steaming API. its showing tweet.retweeted = FALSE for a tweet which is a retweet actually.

Comment: how are you calling the streaming api and the tweet? I think retweeted is always `FALSE` useless you use the `include_my_retweet=1` parameter when requesting timelines, or check `retweet_count`. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/twitter-development-talk/exTRtbZmvro/owGa7yx8mpUJ

Comment: Also check this similar question [Twitter API: Check if a tweet is a retweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869688/twitter-api-check-if-a-tweet-is-a-retweet)

Comment: new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200 , include_rts=True) for  tweets in all tweets:  print(tweet.retweeted)                       i'm using this format and its showing FALSE  for every tweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Tweepy docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#favorite-methods):

> `API.favorites([id][, page])`
>
> Returns the favorite statuses for the authenticating user or user specified by the ID parameter.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `id` – The ID or screen name of the user to request favorites
> - `page` – Specifies the page of results to retrieve. Note: there are pagination limits.
>
> Return type:
>
> - list of `Status` objects

So you had it almost right, I'm not sure where you got the `list` method from but remove it and you'll get the list of tweets you want:

```
tweet_list = api.favorites(screen_name="your_username", count=10)
```